# retrieving the ip of an android websocket server from a javascript client

Tags: android, websocket, java-websocket

i wrote an app which acts as websocket server (with the TooTallNate library), and some javascript that acts as websocket client. i managed to access the numbers and the contact-groups of the connected android device from the browser, and can write sms by typing them on the computer. the problem is that so far i need to hardcode the ip of the android device into the javascript of the client.

this is how i connect the web client to the android server.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.xxx.x.xx:8080/");
```

i want that the user can enter the link for the web-client and then connect to the android device without knowing the ip of it.

how can i retrieve the ip of the server programmatically?

EDIT:

so far for the android socket server i am using the ip which is returned by this method

```
 private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return ip;
}
```

and later i start the server like this

```
final String host = getIpAddress();
    final int port = 8080;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer(MainActivity.this, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));


            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                            + port);
                }
            });

            server.run();
        }
    }).start();
```

when i open the browser with the javascript client i use the same ip that was returned by the java method above.

Comment: Are you just trying to connect from the browser to a socket server on your own device?  If so, you can use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to represent the computer that you are currently running on.

Comment: i just edited my question. when i replace the ip which i use now with localhost it does not work.

Comment: but yes, i try to conntect from the browser to an my own mobile phone, which is in the same wifi network.

Comment: I don'tknow for a fact that localHost works on an Android device.  Did you also try 127.0.0.1? Do you have an actual webSocket server that listens for webSocket protocol connections?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 did not work either. i dont have any listener on the server for web socket connections. the problem is that i can not automatically connect because i dont know the ip, so i can also not listen to any connections.

Comment: If you don't have a listener for webSocket connections, then that's your first problem.  You don't need to know the IP to listen for incoming connections.  You only need to know the port you want to listen on.

Comment: i searched for a longer time for websocketserver-listeners, but none of the help matched my problem. actually, i dont need the server to know the ip of the client, i need the client to know the ip of the server, so that i am able to connect to it with the client javascript: var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.xxx.x.xx:8080/")

depending on which mobile device is used as server, it has a different ip and therefore the client of the browser needs to know the actually ip of the device. 

can you show me a link to a totorial that could help me?

Comment: If you're using the TooTallNate library, shouldn't your server be derived from the WebSocketServer class so it supports the WebSocket protocol?  Here's an example using that library: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ChatServer.java

Comment: yes i know that sample and used it right from the beginning. still i have no idea what to do so that the javascript browser client knows the ip of the android device that acts as server. because as long as i am not able to perform the client javascript connect (new WebSocket("ws://192.xxx.x.xx:8080/"), where i need already the servers ip), the server does not even know about that client, as far as i understood, because its not connected. i need code for the client, telling me wich ips are existing, to chose the right one in order to be able to use it for the connection to the the server.

Comment: Your code makes an instance of `SimpleServer`.   How is that a server capable of the `WebSocket` protocol?  You seem to be fixated on the IP address issue which should work fine with `127.0.0.1`.  I'm thinking that your server doesn't speak the `WebSocket` protocol which would cause the client to fail to connect.

Comment: SimpleServer is derived from WebSocketServer, and my app is already communicating perfectly with the client. i can remote controll my android device from the browser perfectly. the only problem is that so far i need to hardcode the ip of the current android device in the javascript client and i would like to get that ip automatically.

Comment: i took the SimpleServer from that code: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

So, where does http server with HTML and JS? Or is it just HTML page on your computer?

- If it's on your Android phone, you could use `window.location` to get IP of server and put into `new WebSocket();` function
- If it's on another server, you can write some app on that server to receive reports from your Android app to store IP, and then put it to your JS. You could implement it on your computer with some Apache and Java application

Comment: May i know how socket is able to find perticular mobile using window.location